# Interpolate missing values in a query by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Given the following query

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Created]), 0) [Date], 
    [Type], COUNT(*) as [Total]
FROM 
    Submissions 
WHERE 
    [Offer] = 'template1'
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Created]), 0), 
    [Type]
ORDER BY 1;
```

I get the following output:

```
Date                    Type                 Total
----------------------- -------------------- -----------
2021-04-30 00:00:00.000 Online               1
2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 Mail                 1
2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 Online               2
2021-05-10 00:00:00.000 Mail                 1
```

My goal is to ensure that for each date, both types are summarized. In the event that no rows for a given type exist, I'd like to show 0 instead of missing the row entirely. How can I reform the query so that, for example, 2 rows exist for 2021-04-30, one with type Online as shown, and one with type Mail with a total of 0?

I got it working using something like below, but this seems like a pretty brute force way of going about it.

```
SELECT [Date], [Type], [Total] FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Created]), 0) [Date],
        [Type]
    FROM 
        Submissions
    WHERE [Offer] = 'template1'
 ) t1
PIVOT (
    COUNT([Type])
    FOR [Type] in ([Mail],[Online])
) p
UNPIVOT 
(
    [Total] FOR [Type] in ([Mail],[Online])
) p2
```

This results in what I am looking for:

```
Date                    Type                Total
----------------------- ------------------- -----------
2021-04-30 00:00:00.000 Mail                0
2021-04-30 00:00:00.000 Online              1
2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 Mail                1
2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 Online              2
2021-05-10 00:00:00.000 Mail                1
2021-05-10 00:00:00.000 Online              0
```

Comment: Read about using _calendar_ tables.  Basically, you need to maintain a separate table having all dates which you want to appear in your final output.

Comment: I'm already using a calendar table elsewhere in the query. This is an inner query I extracted for the purpose of the question. Adding a query that works to see if there's  abetter way. See revised question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even your brute force approach doesn't work if the submission table has no rows for a particular date.

The standard approach is to use dimension tables to create a template of all the rows you desire, then left join your fact table on to it.

```
SELECT
  calendar.date,
  type.label,
  COUNT(fact.id)
FROM
  calendar
CROSS JOIN
  type
LEFT JOIN
  submissions AS fact
    ON  fact.created >= calendar.date
    AND fact.created <  calendar.date + 1
    AND fact.type     = type.label
    AND fact.offer    = 'template1'
WHERE
    calendar.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
    AND type.label IN ('Mail', 'Online')
GROUP BY
  calendar.date,
  type.label
```

Comment: Cross join on a calendar table was indeed the missing step. Cross join isn't something I use regularly, so it completely slipped my mind. Thanks!